# Flutter Scrollcontroller maxScrollExtent doesn't go till the end of list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

it stops before last element in  list. Is there a way to go till the end container of the  last element

[image]

````
        controller
          ..animateTo(
            controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
            curve: Curves.easeIn,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          );
      });```
````

Comment: may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57645089/flutter-listview-get-full-size-of-scrollcontroller-after-adding-item-to-list/57645944#57645944

Comment: tried that one it doesn't work on singlechildScrollView

Comment: Experiencing same issue: If scrolling animation is performed from addPostFrameCallback sometimes the ListView isn't scrolled exactly to the bottom.
The following sometimes doesn't scroll fully a list to the end:
`SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback ((_) {
  _scrollController.animateTo (_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent, duration: const Duration (milliseconds: chatTimeForScrollingAnimation), curve: Curves.easeOut);
});`
But if we add some time delay before animation/jump call (as proposed by @LIONELVSV)  the issue is gone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Without Animation Solved the  Problem

```
Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
        controller.jumpTo(controller.position.maxScrollExtent);
      });
```

Comment: Also works with 'animateTo'. The time delay itself solves this problem which seems to be a bug in Flutter.

Answer (score 6):

In my case the problem was that the elements were not equal in size and the size was not known until rendered. So, the `ListView` scrolled to its initial estimated `maxScrollExtent` but while scrolling the elements were rendered and the new `maxScrollExtent` was bigger. I hacked it by giving it a much bigger value initially:

```
attachmentsScrollController.animateTo(
  attachmentsScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent * 2,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
  curve: Curves.easeInOut);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the  best function to **scroll to bottom** with a good animation

```
scrollToBottom() {
if (_chatController.hasClients) {
      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500)).then((value) {
        _chatController.animateTo(
          _chatController.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        );
      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with CustomeScrollView widget, and I solved with this.

```
CustomScrollView(
                  controller: Get.find<ChatController>(tag: 'chatDetail')
                      .scrollController
                      .value,
                  reverse: true,
                  keyboardDismissBehavior:
                      ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  cacheExtent: 99999, // <-- here !!! ADD THIS CODE
                  slivers: [
                    ChatList(
                      isQuestion: isQuestion,
                      postCreatedAt: postCreatedAt,
                      title: title,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

my scroll function was normal as we talked before.

```
 void chatScrollUp() async {
await scrollController.value.animateTo(
    scrollController.value.position.maxScrollExtent,
    duration: Duration(
        milliseconds:
            (scrollController.value.position.maxScrollExtent / 2).round()),
    curve: Curves.easeOutCirc);}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked with me is this:

```
 void scrollAnimateToEnd(ScrollController controller) {
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 400)).then((_) {
  try {
    controller
        .animateTo(
      controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    )
        .then((value) {
      controller.animateTo(
        controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      );
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print('error on scroll $e');
  }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The timer is not the right approach. It is only a work around instead.

The issue is because `maxScrollExtent` property of a `ScrollPosition` is called before the widget is fully built, so the code does not know the `maxScrollExtent`.

To solve this, add a

```
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      // Your code here will run after the current frame is painted.
      if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
        _scrollController.animateTo(
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        );
       }
    });
```

as a callback in `initState()` or your other stateful widgets.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by using SingleChildScrollView instead of ListView.