# Event when maxScrollExtent of Scroll controller is changed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

everyone.
How can I detect whether maxScrollExtent of Scroll controller is changed or not when I add children into Listview or Grid dynamically?

Comment: Sergej!
You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141148/how-to-get-full-size-of-a-scrollcontroller