# flutter auto scroll to a specific element

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to do auto scrolling in flutter but it seems there is too little information to do.

I am building some card like this

```
Container(
   child: Column(children: prepareCardWidgets(match[index]))
 )

List<Widget> prepareCardWidgets(data) {
   List<Widget> widgets = [];
   data.forEach((item) {
   widgets.add(UpcomingMatchesCards(item));
 });

 return widgets;
}
```

in `item` variable there are some variable called `item.round` and it's value is integer. I want to auto scroll on page load to any round dynamically.

How can I do it in this case?

Thank you so much.

Comment: and what does `round` field describe? what deos it mean if it is equal to `10` for example?

Comment: Follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46864763/how-to-automatically-scroll-to-end-of-grid-view?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: round can be from 0 to 7

Comment: @Zulfiqar this answer is good but in my case I don't where to scroll. It is fully dynamic.

Comment: ok, so what does it mean if `round` == 5? you want to scroll by 5 pixels?

Comment: I want to scroll where round 5's cards are. 4 cards makes 1 round.