# Render list items then scroll to the bottom

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to render a list then scroll to the bottom.

I understand you can manually scroll to the bottom using `ScrollController` when a new item is added (like in this question: [Programmatically scrolling to the end of a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485529/programmatically-scrolling-to-the-end-of-a-listview)), but how should I automatically scroll to the bottom of the list when the list is built without adding a new item.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage();

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(
            child: new ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 200,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return new ListTile(
                  title: new Text("title $index"),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this behavior if you use `reverse: true`

```
child: new ListView.builder(
  reverse: true
```

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html

Comment: Not great if you want your items to come in chronological order (as in the order the user added them). Getting a list to just start at the bottom seems quite difficult.

Comment: @DarkNeuron did you find nay solution for this issue? I want to scroll to the bottom of the list after it gets data rendered after firebase using streambuilder.

Comment: @JayMungara We had the same requirement. We ended up using a hacking timeout. Not a solution I recommend.

Comment: If you reverse the order of the items in the collection and use `reverse: true` you should get the desired behavior.