# Focus the bottom of a ListView ? Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

If I add items dynamically to a listView with a listView.builder, how do I keep the bottom of the list focus ? Like if the list is full, and I add an Item, how do I do to make the other go up and focus the last item without deleting anything ?

Comment: This could help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485529/programmatically-scrolling-to-the-end-of-a-listview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you can take help of `ScrollController` using method `jumpTo()` or `animateTo()` like bellow,

First create instance of

```
ScrollController controller = new ScrollController();
```

Then after registering it with your listview like bellow example

```
ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text("Item List"),
              ),
              controller: controller,
              itemCount: 50,
            ),
```

And finally call `jumTo() or animateTo()` method when new item added or whenever you want to go at bottom like bellow

```
controller.jumpTo(controller.position.maxScrollExtent);
```

Comment: I noticed that it only shows not the last number but the one before the last (at least with the animate method)

Comment: Yes as @SimonB stated  this shows before last , not last

Comment: @Bawantha So how to fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

The Accepted answer is correct but also this answer will be useful,

//Controller

```
ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
```

//Add this controller to list

```
ListView.builder(
      controller: _scrollController, //The Controller
      shrinkWrap: true,
      reverse: false,
      itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      //Your Widgets
 })
```

// Add this to everytime you want to scroll to the bottm of list

```
_scrollController.animateTo(
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        curve: Curves.easeOut,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

These answers don't make your list Focused at the bottom by default, I used this trick hope it helps :
first reverse the list you gave to the `ListView.builder` an then add this property to your ListView : `reverse: true`

Answer (score 0):

#### Efficient Solution:

This solution keeps the `ListView` focused at the bottom by default, and does not require any scroll controller. So you don't have to worry about where to initialze your scroll controller .

```dart
int list_length; // length of your very long list
List long_list; // your long list of items

ListView.builder(
    reverse: true,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: item_length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index)=>Text(
        '${long_list[list_length-index-1]}'
    ))
)
```

Happy Coding !!