# how can I scroll list view to the bottom in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, scroll, chat

I have a flutter app contain a list view builder
(chat page)
I need to scroll the page to the end of the page to the last message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically scrolling to the end of a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485529/programmatically-scrolling-to-the-end-of-a-listview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to create a scrollController and pass that to the ListView and run a code like this:

```
class SampleList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleListState createState() => _SampleListState();
}

class _SampleListState extends State<SampleList> {
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      controller: _scrollController,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) => ListTile(
        title: Text(
          index.toString(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void scrollToBottom() {
    final bottomOffset = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
    _scrollController.animateTo(
      bottomOffset,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: and where is the call of scrollToBottom()

Comment: @Husamuldeen That is up to you. You can call it whenever you load a new message or whatever makes sense to you.

Comment: I tryed to call it in the initate or in the build method but I got red screen

Comment: @Husamuldeen You have to call the method after the widgets have been laid out.

Comment: please wxplain that for me, how to do that

Comment: after a lot of trying I could do it with timer in the initState but it didn;t work when I press button

Comment: @Husamuldeen When do you need to go to the bottom of the list? After a new element is loaded? Or when the user presses something?

Comment: it is a chat, when the user send a new message it's add a new element to the list and the list view scroling down.

Comment: @Husamuldeen How are you displaying the chat message? Stream builder? You just have to call the scroll to the bottom method every your chat loading mechanism is fired.

Answer (score 8):

Setting reverse: true to ListView widget will bring the newest element at the bottom. With this, you can achieve a chat timeline easily.

```
ListView.builder(
  reverse: true,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => _chatCell(),
)
```

Comment: I don't want to reverse it, I want to scroll down it, the answer before it work when I use timer I the initState, I need do it with every new message.

Comment: @Husamuldeen Have you actually tried this though? It actually works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the object of ScrollController class in the initState method.

Remember :- 1) Call the super.initState(); at the top of the initState method.
2) ListView should be connected with the scroll controller's object.

> WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
> scrollController.jumpTo(scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
> });

Then, add the above code at the top of the build method. It will scroll automatically to the bottom of the list view of messages.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect way to do this is by adding

```
reverse: true
```

to the `ListView.builder()` and change the way you give data the list view. Like this.

Instead of retrieving normally, reverse it and give it to the list view builder.

```
<List> _messages = [...];
_messages.reversed.toList();
```

Comment: I'm talking about scrolling not reversing

Comment: By this way, flutter automatically take you to the bottom of chat, and keep you at the bottom when new messages are added to the list view. Let me know if doesn't work.