# How scroll down chat list view when open the chat Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to make my chat messages to scroll down every time I open a someone's chat. I have tried with jumpTo(), but i didn't worked out. Maybe someone have any clue how to make it work? Thank you in advance!

**Here is the code snippet**

```
Widget ChatMessageList() {
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: chatMessageStream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return snapshot.hasData
        ? ListView.builder(
            controller: controller,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return MessageTile(
                snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["message"],
                snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["sendBy"] ==
                    Constants.myName,

              );
              controller.jumpTo(controller.position.maxScrollExtent);
            },
          )
        : Container();},);}
```

[image: before]

[image: after working ScrollController]

Comment: It may help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485529/programmatically-scrolling-to-the-end-of-a-listview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ListView.builder()` has a parameter named `reverse`. This is false by default, if you change it to `true` you probably achieve what you want to achieve.

```dart
ListView.builder(
      reverse: true,
);
```

Comment: It worked thanks, but just in case data needs to be descending

Comment: if you want your list to be reversed as well, call `snapshot.data.docs.reversed` like @matr0s posted below, but happy to help

Answer (score 2):

If your main goal is to get the latest messages first you can use Reverse for the Snapshot

```
final messages = snapshot.data.docs.reversed;
```

I hope you got the point

Comment: I'm sorry, but i didn't fully understand. Can you give a link example or explain it.

Comment: I can't get a quick and exact example, but I did similar in my app:
* You have a variable where you save you reversed Snapshot:  final messages = snapshot.data.docs.reversed;

* Get necessary data and put in separate variables: 
 List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
          for (var message in messages) {
            final messageText = message.data()['text'];
            final messageSender = message.data()['sender'];
            final currentUser = logedInUser.email;

 .......

Comment: .........
           final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
              sender: messageSender,
              text: messageText,
              isMe: currentUser == messageSender,
            );
            messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
          }

Comment: Not sure if it's clear.  I Will try to share more data once have more time

Comment: Now i got the point, I've tried it, but I'd got error on 'MessageBubble' "The name 'MessageBubble' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument." Take your time :)

Comment: MessageBubble - that's my custom widget, I used four UI elements. You can actually ignore it and just show Snapshot data in your widget (I guess it is MesageTile in your case)

Comment: Dyakuyu @matr0s, for your time and help!