# How to get ListView Component to scroll up on TextFieldInput

Tags: flutter, dart, android-widget

UPDATE 7/15/2021:

I found another similar question that helped me a bit:
[Programmatically scrolling to the end of a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485529/programmatically-scrolling-to-the-end-of-a-listview)

As of now I am able to get it somewhat looking like what I want it to, but I am still getting an overflow issue.

Here is the updated Code

`home.dart`

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  // added a scroll controller to control my ListView
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController(); 

  void addEntry() {
    setState(() {
      entryTextController.text = '';
      this.newEntry = !this.newEntry;
    });

  // on adding an item, I will scroll up in the ListView
    Timer(
        Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        () =>
        scrollController.jumpTo(scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent)
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(), 

               // instead of just the EntryList, I added a container
               // with a fixed height. I'll probably change this later
               Container(
               height: 500.0,
               child: EntriesList(props)
            )
          
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onTap: addEntry)
        );
  }
}
```

`EntryList.dart`

```dart
class _EntriesListState extends State<EntriesList> {
    List<Widget> getEntries(snapshot) {

      myList = entryList.map<Widget>((entry) { 
        return Entry();
      }).toList();

      myList.add(Visibility(                  
          visible: widget.newEntry,
          child: Card(
              child: ListTile(
            title: TextFormField(),
          ))));

     // This is the newest change. By adding a Placeholder, I am able to 
     // bring the screen up on the scrollController bringing this into 
    // position so that the user can then see the TextFormField

      myList.add(Opacity(opacity: 0.0, child: Placeholder()))
    return myList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _entryStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {

        // Async code here ... 

        return ListView(                     
          children: getEntries(snapshot),    
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          shrinkWrap: true,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image: gif]

ORIGINAL:

I'm working on adding an entry to my ListView widget. Within my ListView Widget, I have embedded a hidden TextFieldInput that is shown once a user clicks the `addEntry` button.

[image: gif]

My main issue is that once the list gets long enough, my list does not scroll up to allow the user to see their new entry that they are typing.

[image: gif]

Here is my current code. In order to keep my question concise, I have removed some unrelated code.

`main.dart`

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(), // top widget here

            // Scrollable list of dates
            EntriesList(),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton()
        );
  }
}
```

`EntriesList.dart`

```dart
class _EntriesListState extends State<EntriesList> {
  List<Widget> getEntries(snapshot) {
      
      myList = entryList.map<Widget>((entry) { // getting my entry widgets here
        return Entry();
      }).toList();

      myList.add(Visibility(                  // adding my hidden text input widget here
          visible: widget.newEntry,
          child: Card(
              child: ListTile(
            title: TextFormField(),
          ))));
    return myList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _entryStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }


        return ListView(                     // I added several properties in hopes that it would 
          children: getEntries(snapshot),    // work but to no avail
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics:
              BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SingleChildScrollView` widget. Can be used in `HomePage` or `EntriesList` by simply wrapping it with the `SingleChildScrollView` widget. Like this in the home page:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(), // top widget here

            // Scrollable list of dates
            SingleChildScrollView(child:widgetEntriesList()),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton()
        );
  }
}
```

Or like this in the EntriesList:

```
class _EntriesListState extends State<EntriesList> {
  List<Widget> getEntries(snapshot) {
      
      myList = entryList.map<Widget>((entry) { // getting my entry widgets here
        return Entry();
      }).toList();

      myList.add(Visibility(                  // adding my hidden text input widget here
          visible: widget.newEntry,
          child: Card(
              child: ListTile(
            title: TextFormField(),
          ))));
    return myList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _entryStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }


        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child:ListView(                    
            children: getEntries(snapshot),    // work but to no avail
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics:BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          )
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Instead of wrapping `ListView`, you could instead wrap the `StreamBuilder` as well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Unfortunately this did not solve my issue, but I'll keep trying