# Flutter scrollable Text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a text field that needs to scroll to fit text inside it, the result has been achieved with undesirable behavior where the scroll pushes other items down, i need to have a scrollable Text field that does not cause an overflow, below is what has been achieved
[image]

The above Text field has been implemented using below code

```
Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20, 10, 0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              child: Text(
                "123 123 123 123 123 12 3123 123 123 123 123 1233123 123 123 123 123 123 ",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 38.0),
              ),
            ), // your root container
          )),
```

Below is a demonstration of what I want to achieve, what am I missing?

[image]

Comment: I suppose, everything below your appbar is inside `Column`? In that case, you can try to use `Flex` widget

Comment: @DimaRostopira that's right..

Comment: `Flex` with 3 on bottom part and `Flex` on scrollable with 1 will split screen to 75% and 25% parts of screen, will do just fine I think

Comment: You may also try to wrap your `Container` in `Expanded`, but I'm not sure if it will work

Comment: @DimaRostopira Wrapping in Flex worked, just one more issue, the text doesn't scroll as i type, how can i make the text scroll so the user can see the latest typed text ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485529/programmatically-scrolling-to-the-end-of-a-listview

Comment: Try replacing the text using a TextFormField and set readOnly to true, set the height, maxline. Then it will be automatically scrollable when the text exceeds