# How ListView scroll to bottom accurately?

Tags: flutter

It seems `Controller.position.maxScrollExtent` is a predicted value since the bottom items haven't been rendered,`Controller.jumpTo(Controller.position.maxScrollExtent))` can not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically scrolling to the end of a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485529/programmatically-scrolling-to-the-end-of-a-listview)

Answer (score 0):

```
ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

void jumpTo() {
  SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    if (_controller.hasClients) {
      _controller.animateTo(
        _controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        curve: Curves.elasticInOut,
      );
    }
  });
}
```

Assign this _controller to Listview controller

and call jumpTo()