# Chat App ,start page in the bottom as normal chat

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, chat

Working in a chat app. when we navigate to the individual chat screen the screen starts from the top.
On googling, the recommendation was the put
reverse: true,

but it just reverses the list and again starts from the top of the list.
I want to start the page from the bottom as usual chat pages do.

Comment: you need to scroll to the bottom. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485529/programmatically-scrolling-to-the-end-of-a-listview

Comment: Please include codes

Comment: Wrap your widget with `Stack`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach a scroll controller to your listView.

```
ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
```

add the above controller to your listview.

```
ListView.builder(
      controller: _scrollController,
      itemCount: 10,
      itemBuilder: (_, i) => MyItem(i),          
    ),
```

Then call the bottom function in your initState()

```
void _goToBottomPage() {
  _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
}
```