# Flutter chat app UI animation: How to implement autoscrolling feature?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, chat, flutter-animation, autoscroll

please how do i implement this in flutter
[autoscrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8cwU.gif)

I am building a chat app in flutter , and i will love to add this feature where a response is typed and autoscrolled on the screen. Please how do i implement this UI animation in flutter

Comment: Using the scroll controller: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485529/programmatically-scrolling-to-the-end-of-a-listview